# Swift, unable to update table view with more rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

**Goal:** I have a list of Items fetched from server that are displayed in a TableView, the items are divided in 20s. First, I load 20 items, then when scroll reach bottom I need to add the next 20 items.

**Issue**:When I run the update table view I get error

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (40) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (20), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

updating tableview Datasource functions is not working with me, here is the code:

**Detect scroll when it reach bottom**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
}
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let bounds = scrollView.bounds
    let size = scrollView.contentSize
    let inset = scrollView.contentInset
    let y = CGFloat(offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom)
    let h = CGFloat(size.height)

    let reload_distance = CGFloat(-100)

      if (y > (h + reload_distance)) {

            pageNum += 1
            manager.getNewItems(String(pageNum)) //call the JSON
      }
}
```

TableView update code

```
//json response function    
func didReceiveResponse(info: [String : AnyObject]){

    // get the data and set in arrays (e.g. names[])
    // Then I reload my table and show first 20 Items MyTable.reload()
    // Working fine until here

   if pageNum > 0{

     //names.count is 40 now

     self.MyTable.beginUpdates()

                                             //I tried names.count-20 here
     tableView(MyTable, numberOfRowsInSection: (names.count))
               MyTable.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
               NSIndexPath(forRow: (names.count)-20, inSection: 0)
               ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)


            MyTable.endUpdates()
     }
}
```

of course loading first 20 is perfectly working, the scroll perfectly call the function, everything work only the update fails.

I am puzzling with this riddle for 4 day, couldn't find any working solutions online. Your help is really needed guys :)

thanks

Edit:

This is how I fill the data in tableView

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let MyReturnCell = MyTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    MyReturnCell.name!.text = names[indexPath.row]
    //and so on until I fill all the data inside the MyCell

           return MyReturnCell
```

}

Comment: By the way is your `getNewItems` updating `names` asynchronously? If so, you should be wary of that. It's much safer to add items to `names` and the insert the rows in the table view at the same time. It avoids any potential of these two getting out of sync. For example, do query to build array of just the 20 items; then in one routine, add these to `names`, and then immediately call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` with the index paths of these 20 new rows to be shown in the table.

Comment: getNewItems run before the update, manage is delegate to the class and, then its  protocol func didReceiveResponse() will catch any updates, and inside it I loop through the data and insert in arrays, and after the loop finish and all data are fetched I run the code tableUpdate, I believe its synched correctly

Comment: Great. You'd be surprised how often I see code here were someone blithely is adding items to their model array from, for example, the `NSURLSession` completion handler running on some background queue, oblivious of the need to dispatch the updating of both the array and the table view back to the main thread. Sounds like you've got that covered, tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code example may help you understand what you need to do:

1. Create an array of index paths
2. Add the 20 data objects which you received from the server in your data source.
3. Now since your data source and array of index paths are on the same page, begin table view updates and insert the rows.

That's it. :)

Created a dummy project to answer. When you run the project and scroll, you'll see that the rows are added dynamically.
https://github.com/harsh62/stackoverflow_insert_dynamic_rows

```
func insertRows() {
    let newData = ["Steve", "Bill", "Linus", "Bret"]
    let olderCount: Int = self.names.count

    names += newData

    var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
    for i in 0..<newData.count {//hardcoded 20, this should be the number of new results received
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: olderCount + i, inSection: 0))
    }
    // tell the table view to update (at all of the inserted index paths)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Top)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Honestly I didn't understand :) what do you mean with datasource?  and how/where to use this function? .addObjects ?

Comment: The variable mentioned by me `dataSource` will be the array which you will be using in the `cellForRowAtIndex` to insert some data into `UITableViewCell's`.

Comment: so I need to update index path inside the function cellForRowAtIndexPath to make it work? in my case I add data differently I will add it under Edit in my question so you could imagine what I do

Comment: No not at all, you are getting it wrong. Follow the steps am saying: 1. Add objects to your array(data source for tableview) when you receive new data. 2. Build new index paths which you would like to insert in the table View 3. Follow my last three steps in the function which i answered i.e. to update the tableView

Comment: When you receive the response, update your `names` array by appending more objects to it

Comment: yes I do that I append, and  when I print its counting 40

Comment: when update function is triggered its names.count = the total numbers of data (old and new)

Comment: I have edited my answer. When you check the count, just call the function in my answer. You should be good to go.

Comment: I get cannot convert value of type [AnyObjec] to expected NSIndexPath

Comment: Just use NSIndexPath instead of AnyObject

Comment: "attempt to insert row 40 into section 0, but there are only 40 rows in section 0 after the update" error!! it seems Swift dont want me to update the table lol

Comment: Sorry for the wrong advice, the reason you are getting is this because you are trying to insert 40 rows but instead you only need to insert 20. Edited my answer.

Comment: Oh actually I was running that (I put 20 insted of dataToAdd) I assumed this is what it will be in my scenario before.. so this error appeared actually when there was 20

Comment: this is so puzzling.. what do you think mate? any suggestions?

Comment: Let me create a dummy project for you. ;)

Comment: Wait Wait.. it worked when I used (self.names.count - 20) wooho lol

Comment: edit your answer with the (- 20) thing for those who will suffer in the future as well XD And thank you loads mate, Cheers!

Comment: I created a project though. Added that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`, the number of row present in your data source must be equal to the previous count plus the number of rows being inserted. But you appear to be inserting one `NSIndexPath` in the table, but your `names` array presumably has 20 more items. So, make sure that the number of `NSIndexPath` items in the array passed to `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` is equal to the number of rows that have been added to `names`.